# Birational contraction to a $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein Variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

Given a birational contraction morphism $X\rightarrow Y$
of complex normal algebraic varieties. 
If $Y$ is a smooth variety, what kind of singularities can appear
on $X$?

I would be grateful of any reference that point to this question. 
Im principally interested in know if the singularities of $X$ can be log-terminal.

In the case that im studying $X$ is toroidal so i have only to prove that
$X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein. If $X$ projective then it follows easy.
It is true in general?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you define what you call a birational contraction?

Comment: Since $Y$ is smooth it seems to me that if $X\rightarrow Y$ is divisorial then it should be a weighted blow-up.

Comment: A proper morphism $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$, with a divisor $E$ of $X$, such that $dim(f(E))<dim(E)$ and $X-E\rightarrow Y-f(E)$ is an isomorphism.